# (L'Étranger de Camus) "bouts" without an article in "des souliers à bouts carrés"

Tags: prépositions, articles

Why is there no article before *bouts* in this sentence?

> Un peu plus tard passèrent les jeunes gens du faubourg, cheveux laqués et cravate rouge, le veston très cintré, avec une pochette brodée et des souliers à **bouts** carrés.

**Motivation for the question**

My French grammar book says, "It is so usual to put in the article, that perhaps it would have been easier to learn when to leave it out," and goes on to list the exceptions, e.g. in proverbs, in lists, in titles, often after *de* etc.

But none of them seem to fit *bouts* above.

My one (wild) guess is that it might be the influence of set phrases like *à bout de souffle* and *à bout portant*.

In sum, I would like an answer to explain which recognized exception applies to the above case or, if none apply, what considerations make it "sound right" without an article.  Thanks.

Comment: I can't say why there is no article. All I can say is when *à* introduces a distinctive feature there is no article. If the same idea were expressed using *avec*,  we'd have an article. *Un veston à pochette brodée / des souliers avec des bouts carrés*. *Un casque à pointe* (= *avec une pointe*). *Une roue à aube* (= *avec une aube*), *à poings fermés* (= *avec les poings fermés*)...  In *À bout de souffle* "à" has a different meaning and it would not be possible to substitute "à" with "avec+art.".  Same with *à bout portant*, *à bout de souffle*, *à brûle-pourpoint* which are set phrases.

Comment: Ah, thank you!  That "when *à* introduces a distinctive feature there is no article" is to me a general statement of exception, one my grammar book failed to mention. I also see that *bout* in the set phrases have a figurative meaning, and the *avec* test really brings out the difference.

Answer (score 3):

"à bouts carrés" (square-ended) is used to specify the type of shoes. The syntax is similar to "animaux à longues oreilles" translated as "animals with long ears", without article before ears/oreilles in French as in English.

Comment: +1 Interesting points and comparisons.  Another similarity between those two English terms is that they both have alternate hyphenated translations ('square-toed [shoes]' and 'long-eared [animals]') that both have figurative meanings when applied to humans: 'long-eared'='asinine, stupid' (from an ass/donkey?) and 'square-toed'='exaggeratedly proper/old-fashioned' (from the kind of shoes often associated with "Puritans'?).

Answer (score 3):

Il y a des cas avec ou sans article:

**Cas avec des articles:**

- pour un complément de lieu: la maison à la campagne;
- des composants : une tarte à la crème, aux fraises, aux poires;
- pour des constructions (peu heureuses) signifiant l'appartenance: la maison à ma tante.

**Cas sans article:**

Pour exprimer des composants:

- Roue à aubes: roue avec des aubes;
- chapeau à pompons: avec des pompons, comme l'exemple souliers à bouts carrés;
- casque à pointe;
- chaussure à clous;
- **mais tarte aux fraises. Il semble que dans le domaine culinaire, on emploie des articles définis pour accentuer le style: soupe aux légumes, sauce aux champignons, plat aux truffes.**

Pour un usage /une destination: pelle à tarte, cuiller à poisson, couteau à découper, tête à claques, parc à thèmes, rasoir à barbe, lampe à bronzer/à bronzage.

On peut quasiment construire ce que l'on veut: *un sapin à tortues* (pour les tortues, ou qui contiendrait des tortues), **mais**: *une soupe aux tortues* (sic).

**Autre cas: Grevisse 14, 355 b:**

Les compléments de noms désignant des récipients sont introduits par *à* s'il s'agit de la destination, et par *de* quand on envisage le contenu:

boîte à poudre, boîte à clous

Voir aussi l'emploi de *de*, plus fréquent: [Using "de" vs an adjective](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16602/using-de-vs-an-adjective/17101#17101)