# Using "de" vs an adjective

Tags: prépositions, adjectifs, noms, de

It seems that in French there are a few ways to provide extra attributes to a noun.

1. With *de*, e.g. *salle de bains*
2. With an adjective, e.g. *chapeau rouge*

Is there some rule outside of common expressions on deciding which one to use?

Example: what's the difference between *voiture de commerce* and *voiture commerciale*?  This might be a bad example in terms of meaning but the grammatical structure is right.

Answer (score 2):

**Adjectif:**

L'usage est assez simple et direct, et l'interprétation aussi, donc. Il porte directement sur le nom. Comme chapeau rouge. En revanche voiture *commerciale* est peu usité. On parle plutôt de pratique *commerciale*, de geste *commercial*, un agent *commercial*.

Le terme voiture de commerce est lui aussi peu usité et ambiguë. On parle de navire de commerce (par opposition à navire de plaisance, de passagers), mais avion et train de fret / de passagers. On emploie plus souvent véhicule que voiture pour des usages professionnels. On trouve des camionnettes de commerce (plutôt que de transport de matériel).

**De**

Suivi d'un mot avec substantif, c'est l'appartenance: La maison de ma tante.

Avec des mots sans substantif:

Il peut être utilisé pour de nombreuses précisions. Grevisse signale que De introduit des compléments de sens très divers, avec une certaine tendance à substituer à *de* des compléments plus spécialisés (14, 355).

- contenant/contenu : sac de grains: sac *à* grains
- (outil) pour usage/lieu: serviette de plage, serviette de bain: ou serviette *pour la* plage, *pour le* bain , salle de spectacle, etc.
- idem avec école de filles: *pour* filles
- idem avec femme de ménage (femme de journée, peu usité), hôpital de jour, tarif de nuit
- matière: cheminée de marbre : ou cheminée *en* marbre
- composants: confiture de fraises, compote de pommes
- direction ou provenance: le train de Paris (*depuis* Paris ou *vers* Paris).
- origine: saumon d'élevage: provenant d'un élevage
- enfin, il y a des expressions avec un sens spécifique: pomme de pain (pinecone). Il y en a beaucoup.

Comment: +1 One question about the example expression given in your last point. It's not capitalized so it's probably not referring to the sandwich shop. Is it another way to say "boule de pain"/("pain en boule"), just a small typo, or something else?

Comment: @PapaPoule . I added it: pinecone. boule de pain is correct, more direct that pain en boule, pain rond. I dont see any other.

Comment: What do you mean by *avec substantif*? Do you mean with a *determiner*?

Answer (score 0):

Good question @Honza Pokorny.
As often with French language, it depends on each case :-)

"salle de bains" is a word in itself. It means "bathroom", no less, no more.
"chapeau rouge" is different, there are two distinct words: "chapeau" (hat) and "rouge" (red). So you could write "chapeau vert" (green hat), "chapeau bleu" (bleu hat), etc.

Concerning "voiture de commerce" and "voiture commerciale", it is more difficult to explain the difference:

1. "voiture de commerce" is correct from a grammatical point of view,
   but never used in French.
2. "voiture commerciale" means that a car is
       specifically used for commercial activities.

Answer (score 0):

*De*, when it's a preposition, is used to introduce a complement. 
However, an adjective doesn't come with a preposition. An adjective in French can have the function of *epithète du nom*, when bound to a noun without a verb, or an *attribut du sujet*, when bound to a noun by a stative verb.

- *Épithete du nom*:

  > Les gens heureux parlent de bonheur.

  Heureux is the adjective
- *Attribut du sujet*:

  > Les gens heureux ne sont pas tristes.

  Adjectives like *tristes* that come with a *verbe attributif* (a sort of verb used for the state of being, like *être*).

So in conclusion, adjectives don't come with a preposition (like *de*).

What I explained here may not be easy to understand so if you have questions don't hesitate.

Answer (score 0):

The rules seem elusive and we get free variations, preferences and strict selection.

- la ***conquête spatiale*** vs la ***conquête de l'espace***
- un *problème mathématique* vs un ***problème de mathématiques***
- son ***groupe sanguin*** vs son *?groupe de sang*

This situation is even used to spot attributive adjectives, by [Daille (1999)](http://www.atala.org/taln_archives/TALN/TALN-1999/taln-1999-long-010.pdf), for example.

Comment: groupe de sang est rarissime en France. les statistiques suivantes montrent quelques (après les découvertes du 20eme siècle): https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=groupe+de+sang&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgroupe%20de%20sang%3B%2Cc0