# Using à to describe physical characteristics: with or without the definite article?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, à

I was under the impression that one used an article, e.g. `un homme aux yeux bleus` (or `un homme au parapluie`, for that matter). But I see that it's not always the case: as a somewhat random example, my dictionary defines a "satyre" as "une divinité de la terre, être à corps humain, à cornes et à pieds de bouc." As another example, [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A0) includes: "Cet enfant d'une extrême beauté, aux yeux bleu vif, aux cheveux blonds bouclés, à teint délicat..."

Is there a rule for when to include the definite article?

Edit: looks like [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16329/l%C3%89tranger-de-camus-bouts-without-an-article-in-des-souliers-%C3%A0-bouts-carr%C3%A9s) is along the same lines.

Comment: Yes, but also `aux yeux`, `aux cheveux`, and yet `à teint`, even thought I've also seen `au teint`.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that--my point is, why is there an article (aux) for `yeux` and `cheveux`, but not for `teint`? Likewise, why is there no article for `corps`, `cornes`, and `pieds`?

Comment: Good point there, I see it now. I find _à teint_ surprising personally, whereas I find everything else pretty normal. It's possible à adds a property to what precedes, whereas with the article would make it a composition of sorts? Interesting stuff, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form with the article is more "intense", and is used to mark a distinction:

- une couturière aux doigts de fées (an uncommon gifted seamstress)
- une couturière à doigts de fée (one of many gifted seamstresses)

In the exemple above, I would think that the author emphasizes that the beauty comes more from the eyes and the hair than from the fair skin.